# Best algorithm to find an element in an ordered list

Tags: java, algorithm, iteration

> There is list `A` which contains numbers in ascending order.
>
> Similarly a list `B` which also contains numbers in ascending order.
>
> The result should be list `C` which contains numbers from `A` which are not in `B`.

My Solution:

I iterated through `A` and checked for the number in `B` using `.contains()` and added the required elements in `C`.

I was told using `.contains()` is higher order of complexity O(n).

Does anyone have a better solution?

Comment: Well, you know that the lists are sorted, so you don't have to search through B all the time, you can search through A and B at once.

Answer (score 5):

Yes, your method will get O(n^2). The idea to get O(n) is just like merging two sorted lists into one. Merging two sorted lists into one is a Union. Finding common elements in two sorted lists is an Intersection. Your problem is to find the set difference of two sorted lists. Drawing a simple example on paper, you will find you can use two iterators to do it in O(n) time.

Comment: Two iterators at one time? May I know how it is possible?

Comment: See @Vikram Bhat's answer.

Answer (score 3):

Use Merge Sort like merge routine to add element from A lists into C using following conditions:-

`if (B->data<A->data)` just iterate B

`if(B->data==A->data)` iterate A & B

`if(A->data<B->data)` Add A->data to C and iterate A

Time complexity `O(N)`

Comment: You have a bad condition in the first `if`, it should be `B->data < A->data`. Also, if duplicates are allowed, the second `if` isn't so accurate.

Comment: @pkacprzak bad mistake thnx for telling corrected it

Comment: how about the idea of adding all the elements in a hashset and retrieving them using .contains() method?

Comment: @LGAP No it would find the union of the sets not the difference A-B

Comment: @LGAP's idea of using a hashset also works to get O(n) time complexity and to get the set difference. But add O(n) space overhead.